# Chrome cast Notification click not working on less than api level 21

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

App crashing with

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.espn.score_center/com.framework.chromecast.CastNotificationActivity flg=0x10 bnds=[0,633][1080,971] (has extras) } in afj@439752a8

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5727)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: getTasks() from pid=4624, uid=10257 requires android.permission.GET_TASKS

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getTasks(ActivityManagerNative.java:2860)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.app.ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(ActivityManager.java:851)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.app.ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(ActivityManager.java:887)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at afj.onReceive(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:89)

E/AndroidRuntime( 4624):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:763)
```

Comment: GET_TASK permission been deprecated in api level 21.